# Auto Login in script payload data not being encoded correctly - are there ways around this?

Tags: google-apps-script

Setting up a google script to log in to website and download some PDFs into google drive folder. The website will post a csrf-token, user email, and user password. When using UrlFetchApp.getRequest, just to see what it's going to send, getRequest (and .fetch etc) will show me that the function is encoding most of the characters correctly but for my user entered email and password it will not encode those.

From inspecting the post data from when I actually log in it should be 'user%40email.com' (%40 for the @).

But when looking at the request that will be sent from UrlFetchApp.getRequest I see that the email going out is still 'user@email.com'. If I attempt to manually enter %40 for the '@' or use any of the encodeURI the url-encoded email becomes 'user%2540email.com' (meaning, I think, it's encoding the '%' as well).

Thoughts? Work around?

I've tried about every combination I can think of between escape, encodeURI, and encodeURIComponent just hoping something works.

```
var url = 'www.url.com';

var token = 'csrf-token';
var email = 'user@email.com';
var pass = 'pass!word';

var formData = {
 'authenticity_token': token,
 'user[email]': email,
 'user[password]': pass
};

var options = {
  'method': 'post',
  'payload': formData,
  'followRedirects': true
};

var req = UrlFetchApp.getRequest(url, options);
Logger.log(req);
```